# How to extract plain text from html markup in ruby with help of 'Ox' gem

Tags: html, ruby, xml, html-parsing

I have a lot of markup stored in database table text field, this markup could have different structure.
I need to extract plain text from each of these pieces of markup stored in the database, so I decided to use `Ox` gem for this since it the fastest xml parsing library for ruby according to tests. When I try to do it I get errors like this:

```
irb(main):026:0> Ox.parse(some_html)
Ox::ParseError: invalid format, document not terminated at line 1, column 23 [parse.c:521]
```

I know how to do it with `Nokogiri` but I need to use `Ox` library

Comment: Are you sure that your HTML is actually valid XML? HTML might look like and might be XML, but it must not follow the strict rules of XML to still by valid HTML.

Comment: This html is not a valid xml, for example it could contain self closed tags `<img src="logo.png" alt="logo">')`. The main question how to parse and extract text from html which is not always valid xml. Other libraries like `Nokogiri` have such possibility, so probably it could be done with `Ox` as well

Comment: Did you read and try the section about HTML parsing on OX's homepage: http://www.ohler.com/ox/ ?

Comment: @spickermann yes, i tried to change default settings like in documentation, but result is the same: `Ox::ParseError` ...

Comment: Can you please an example document, for example the one that was failing at line 1, column 23 for your question?

Comment: it fails: 
`Ox.parse('<img src="logo.png" alt="logo">')
Ox::ParseError: invalid format, document not terminated at line 1, column 33 [parse.c:521]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For parsing html I should use `Ox.sax_html` method with sax handler, but not `Ox.parse`

```
require 'stringio'
require 'ox'

class TextHandler < ::Ox::Sax
  attr_reader :parsed_text

  def initialize()
    @parsed_text = ''
  end

  def text(value)
    @parsed_text << " #{value}"
  end
end

text_handler = TextHandler.new

options = {
  symbolize: true,
  skip: :skip_white,
  smart: true
}

some_markup = '<img src="logo.png" alt="logo"><div>hello</div><div>world ...'

input = StringIO.new(some_markup)

Ox.sax_html(text_handler, input, options)

text_handler.parsed_text
```